# Allowing user to choose system alarm tone from android app

Tags: android, alarm, audio

following is my onClick() method

```
public void onClick(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnAlarm:
            intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TITLE, "Select Tone");
            intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, (Uri) null);
            this.startActivityForResult(intent, 5);
            break;
    }
}
```

this is my onActivityResult() method-

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == -1 && requestCode == 5) {
        Uri uri = intent.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if(uri!=null){
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(EmergencyContactsActivity.this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem which I am facing is uri variable is always null so the control is not going inside if statement.
I have searched and found the same method every where. Please help me as I am new to android application development.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using the `Intent` used to launch the ringtone picker to retrieve the output `Uri`, use the one passed in from [`Activity.onActivityResult`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29). In other words, change `intent` to `data`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == -1 && requestCode == 5) {
        final Uri uri = data.getParcelableExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_PICKED_URI);
        if (uri != null) {
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, you don't need to pass in `(Uri) null`, this doesn't actually do anything. The extra [`RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI) is used to select a particular ringtone when the ringtone picker opens up. If you wanted to check **Default alarm sound**, you would pass in:

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI, System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
```

Alternatively, if you wanted to check the actual name of the default alarm sound you would pass in:

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_EXISTING_URI,
        RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM));
```

And the ensure the default alarm sound is played when you select **Default alarm sound** you should add the extra [`RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RingtoneManager.html#EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI):

```
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI, System.DEFAULT_ALARM_ALERT_URI);
```

Comment: But setActualDefaultRingtoneUri is not changing the system alarm tone